# how to get the last array with a specific key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking for a function to return an array and all its sub-structure for a specific criteria

**Criteria:**

- php 5.6 compatible
- Return the last instance of array with key name of `!ENTITY` with all
  its values in-tact

**Sample array:**

For the multidimensional array, lets call that `$arr`, for this example structure it's 6 levels deep, we should not assume it's always 6 levels.

```
$arr = array("!ENTITY" =>
             array("!ENTITY" =>
                array("!ENTITY" =>
                    array("!ENTITY" =>
                        array("!ENTITY" =>
                            array("!ENTITY" =>
                                array("svg" => 
                                     array(
                                         0 => array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_2"),
                                         1 => array("g" => "", "@id" => "Layer_3"),
                                     ),
                                     "@version" => 1.2,
                                     "@id" => "Layer_1",
                                ),
                            "@different" => "layer"
                            ),
                        "@all" => "layer"
                        ),
                    "@here" => "layer"
                    ),
                "@goes" => "layer"
                ),
            "@else" => "layer"
            ),
   "@something" => "layer"
   );
```

**Expected Output:**

I would like to return the final array for `!ENTITY` with it's sub-structure all in-tact. Here is a sample of the expected output:

```
Array
    (
        [svg] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [g] => 
                        [@id] => Layer_2
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [g]
                        [@id] => Layer_3
                    )

            )

        [@version] => 1.2
        [@id] => Layer_1
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to recursively traverse the array and return resultant values if found like below:

```
<?php

function getLastValueForKey($data, $key){
    $res = '';
    foreach($data as $k => $value){
        $sub_res = is_array($value) ? getLastValueForKey($value, $key) : '';
        if($sub_res !== ''){
            $res = $sub_res;
        }else if($k === $key){
          $res = $value;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
   
print_r(getLastValueForKey($arr, '!ENTITY'));
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/362727b28e82d9e7547bf4621e4c2f7e24308318)

Comment: this looks great and i love how you set it up to work with other key names too.

Comment: @user3436467 Thanks. Generalizing it for any key is most often a good approach since it provides flexibility throughout the application for any other key

Comment: and its Fast , Good job

Comment: @flakerimi Thanks. Worst case scenario is still visiting all keys in the array since OP wishes to check for last instance of a particular key.

Comment: It does the job, and its clean. I like it.